# what are the consequences of the Azure Function app restart action?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

What will happen to the ongoing running process when the azure function app restart?
The process will be killed or pick again after the restart of the azure function app if automatic retry is on in the function app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after research and try out on dummy functions I found that for some of the trigger functions it retries automatically after some time when the azure function app restart or crash.

- Queue Storage Trigger - Function retry automatically after 10 minutes
- Event Grid Trigger - Function retry automatically after 30 seconds
- HTTP Trigger - Function don't automatically retry at all

Answer (score 1):

When Azure Function App is restarted all active functions are going to be killed.

Check out official documentation about [Azure Funtion App best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices).